# Clojure reduce requires val parameter to accumulate vector

Tags: clojure

I am doing a reduce where I want to accumulate and return a vector. It works fine when done like this:

```
(reduce
  (fn [[res-vec last-rgb] rgb]
    (let [calc-res (mu/colour-distance-L2 last-rgb rgb)
          accum-results (conj res-vec calc-res)]
      [accum-results rgb]))
  []
  colour-selections)
```

However when the `[]` parameter is left out I get `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long`. This occurs because `colour-distance-L2` is being given at least one `java.lang.Long` rather than two vectors as it expects (both vectors of the *type* `[r g b]` - for red green and blue).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579804/clojure-reduce-with-three-parameters) is exactly the kind of reduce I am doing.

I do not need to use the 3-arity version of reduce, because `colour-selections` will always have a size of at least 2. I just put the `[]` as part of the *trial and error* of getting past the run-time error. And as it turns out doing this somehow has a good effect.

Is there some way I can use the 2-arity version of reduce here?

Comment: `I do not need to use the 3-arity version of reduce, because colour-selections will always have a size of at least 2.` I don't even know what would make you think that. The 3 arity version is needed if the first element of your input sequence is not the same type as your accumulator.

Comment: This is my first Clojure reduce. I'm used to Scala folds where you always have a 'seed', so never really had to think in those terms before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only use 2-arity `reduce` provided your reducing function has a signature like (A,A) → A - taking two values of the same type and producing another value of that type.
Yours has a signature of (A,B) → A, where A is a pair `[res-vec last-rgb]`
and B is a triple `[r g b]`. If you want to reduce it over a sequence of B, providing the first A to start the sequence *is necessary*, because the function doesn't know how to make two Bs into an A.

That being said, I'm not quite seeing the need for a `reduce` here. Assuming `res-vec` is the interesting value from your reduction it could also be produced by mapping colour-distance over `colour-selections` and itself less 1 element. Something like

```
(mapv mu/colour-distance-L2 colour-selections (drop 1 colour-selections))
```